# Fields with SO(3) diagonal subgroup symmetry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, group-representations, magnetic-monopoles, higgs

I read about a Higgs field $\vec{\phi}=\frac{1}{2}a\hat{r}\cdot \vec{\sigma}$ (in the context of 't Hooft-Polyakov monopole) with SO(3) diagonal subgroup symmetry consisting of simultaneous and equal rotations in real and isotopic space, wherein $\sigma^i$ is the Pauli matrix, $\hat{r}$ is the spatial unit vector.

I only know a little bit of introductory group theory for physics student. Unfortunately, I cannot see how this form of field $\phi$ comes out. Does it mean that we are **using Pauli matrices as kinda bases of the isotopic space**? If so, why? I've learned nothing about such thing. And by the way, what does *isotopic space* mean?

Comment: The interest is to mix internal degrees of freedom of fields ($\Phi$ is in the adjoint representation of $SO(3)$ or $SU(2)$, so has $3$ components : $\Phi = \Phi^a \sigma_a$ ), and space time degrees of freedom (we have 3 spatial dimensions $r^i$).Writing $\Phi^a = r^a$, may seem very curious, because we mix freedom degrees, which seem to have no relation. The interest is to establish topological structures, for instance, we may consider the unit vector $\hat \phi$, which lives in $S^2$, and a asymptotic sphere in space, also $S^2$, and we could consider mapping between these 2 spheres.

Comment: We are using Pauli matrices for any SU(2) group. Isotopic space is just an internal degree of freedom, allowing any (isospin 1/2) particle to be in "up" or "down" state. For a nucleon it means to be either proton or neutron, for a quark $(u,d)$, for a lepton $(\nu_e,e)$. Halzen & Martin's book contains very good explanations of that.

Comment: @Trimok Why don't you post your comment as an answer? It is hard to answer something better than that.